# How do I force a text field to be upper case only in Swift?

Tags: swift

I would like the text entry on a text field to be upper case only.

Is there a way to limit the text field to output only upper case letters or even limit the software keyboard to only display upper case letters to users?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
let textFieldOutput = "Wait a moment, please."
let newString = textFieldOutput.uppercased()
//The string is now "WAIT A MOMENT, PLEASE."
```

Answer (score 11):

Step-1. In Main.Storyboard select the textfield and click on attribute inspector[image]

Step-2. Then in text input traits -> select 'All Characters' in Capitalization.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Changing the keyboard input type to `All Characters` does not prevent the user to switch back to lowercase letters (at least on iOS 13).
I use the following code (Swift 5.1) to capitalise only new characters added to the textfield instead of setting the full string over and over again as suggested in some other answers.

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let firstLowercaseCharRange = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.lowercaseLetters)
        if let _ = firstLowercaseCharRange {
            if let text = textField.text, text.isEmpty {
                textField.text = string.uppercased()
            }
            else {
                let beginning = textField.beginningOfDocument
                if let start = textField.position(from: beginning, offset: range.location),
                    let end = textField.position(from: start, offset: range.length),
                    let replaceRange = textField.textRange(from: start, to: end) {
                    textField.replace(replaceRange, withText: string.uppercased())
                }
            }
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the text to upper case with

```
string.uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())
```

You can use the method [textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) to change the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the string afterwards to uppercase using the below:

```
var newString = myString.uppercaseString
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two options:

1. Use the `uppercaseString` property of Swift's `String` class to generate an all-uppercase version of the text. This is a reasonable option if you want an upper case version of whatever is typed into the text field.
2. Implement the method `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)` in the text field's delegate. Your implementation should do the replacement itself using an upper case version of the replacement string, and then return `false`. This is the approach you want if it's important that the text appear upper case in the text field.

Answer (score 2):

in swift 3:

```
var newString = myString.uppercased()
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2:
There are two ways.

Firstly. Entered value from keyboard, you can do (upperCase) it in the programmatically.

```
yourTextField.text = yourString.uppercased()
```

Or story board force upper keyboard.

`StorBoard->TextInputTraits->Capitalization->Select ALL Characters`